# Having two IPs for same hostname in hosts file

Tags: dns, ip, hosts, hosts-file, hostname

**Request**
I would like to have my hostname let's say hostA resolve to IP1 if i am at home
and IP2 if i am remote
Is it possible to have two IPs for the same hostname so that it tries them both and takes me to the one that's available

**My Workaround**
currently i just edit my hosts file and switch back and forth

Comment: `/etc/hosts` syntax is one (host)-to-one (ip), so you'll have to do that in a different manner. Why not having two hosts, `athome` and `notathome` and use the needed one each time?

Comment: You can have two entries, but only one will be used! The simplest work-round is what you are doing at present, but automate it by having two versions `hosts.local` and `hosts.remote` and overwrite `hosts` with the appropriate copy. If you log out between local and remote use, then you can automate this in the log-in script, eg by pinging your router to determine if you are local or not.

Comment: @nKn Thank you for your comment, it's a wordpress website so changing site address is bigger pain than just update the host file

Comment: Please explain why the Negative Rating